Identities for Prime Coefficients of Certain Cusp Forms
While working with Fourier expansions of cusp forms of congruence subgroups of the modular group, I observed the following patterns in their prime coefficients.
Let $a(n)$ be the Fourier coefficients of the weight-4 cusp form of $\Gamma_{0}(2)$, and let $b(n)$ be the Fourier coefficients of the weight-2 cusp form of $\Gamma_{0}(4)$. (The OEIS data for these sequences is available here and here respectively.) A small numerical experiment that checked the first 1000 or so primes seems to show that for primes $p>2$:
$$a(p) = p^{3}+1$$
$$b(p) = p+1$$
My questions are:

Are these formulas true, and if so, how does one prove them?
Ramanujan's conjecture states that prime coefficients $\tau(p)$ of the weight-12 cusp form of the modular group satisfy the bound $\left|\tau(p)\right| \leq 2 p^{11/2}$. Since these all pertain to prime coefficients of cusp forms, are these kinds of identities related?

(I apologise if this question is too remedial for this forum. I'm trained as a physicist, not a mathematician, so these kinds of statements are unfamiliar to me. A good reference for learning more about this would be much appreciated, even if a detailed answer is too much to ask for.)

There are no weight 4/2 cusp forms for those groups.

To add to @Kimball's comment, these are clearly coefficients of Eisenstein series.

For A002408, as mentioned in the previous comments, it is not accurate to refer to the source of that sequence as an "8-dimensional cusp form."  For one thing is is not a cusp form.  For another, the term "dimension" is archaic.  These days the term "weight" is standard (and weight is half of what was called dimension).
